# this.attribute is not defined after being constructed

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, undefined

Hi there I made a very small jquery plugin:

```
$mandarina = {
    mainCnt: $('#main'),
    header: $('header.site-header'),
    init: function () {
        this.onScroll();
    },
    onScroll: function () {
        $(window).scroll(function(e){
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            if(scrollTop > this.header.height()){
                this.mainCnt.addClass('fixed-header');
            }else{
                this.mainCnt.removeClass('fixed-header');
            }
        });
    }
}
$(function () {
    $mandarina.init();
});
```

But when I scroll I get this error in console:

```
TypeError: this.header is undefined
[Parar en este error]   

if(scrollTop > this.header.height()){
```

Any idea why?

weird thing is that this.header in the init function it does exist..

Comment: put `if(scrollTop > $mandarina.header.height())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the scroll callback, `this` is the `window` element rather than your `$mandarina` object. You need to save a reference to `$mandarina` via;

```
onScroll: function () {
    var that = this;

    $(window).scroll(function(e){
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(scrollTop > that.header.height()){
            that.mainCnt.addClass('fixed-header');
        }else{
            that.mainCnt.removeClass('fixed-header');
        }
    });
}
```

... i.e. store the value of `this` in `that`, and use `that` instead of `this` inside the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$mandarina = {
mainCnt: $('#main'),
header: $('header.site-header'),
init: function () {
    this.onScroll();
},
onScroll: function () {
    var $this= $(this);
    $(window).scroll(function(e){
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(scrollTop > $this.header.height()){
            $this.mainCnt.addClass('fixed-header');
        }else{
            $this.mainCnt.removeClass('fixed-header');
        }
    });
 }
}

$(function () {
    $mandarina.init();
});
```

Comment: `header` is a property of the `$mandarina` object; accessing it like a variable (`header` directly) won't work.

Comment: You should also declare variables using `var`, otherwise you end up with [implicit globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), or [errors in ES5 strict mode](http://es5.github.io/#C).

Comment: do these browser follow these

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: do any of current mordern browers follow es guidline strictly enough that declaring local variable without var will make a error ?? just want to know, because i never get it

Comment: All modern browsers support ES5 strict mode; it just has to be enabled by the developer using "use strict;".

Answer (score -1):

```
this.header.height
```

you need to remove `this`